# UTL_SMTP open connections is taking too much time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, smtp, oracle12c, aix

Recently we have upgrade oracle database to 12c.

I have facing problem of sending mail through utl_smtp.

Our procedure of sending mail is

so `UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port)` is taking 20 second to open the connection. In earlier it was working fine.

Any solution?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail_xyz 
    (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
     p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
     p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
     p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
     p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
    l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('9.1'||sysdate);
    l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
    dbms_output.put_line('9.2'||sysdate);
    UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
    UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
    UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
    UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

While sending mail through `send_mail_xyz`

and output is

> anonymous block completed
>   9.118-02-2019 12:11:25
>   9.218-02-2019 12:31:25

Comment: *"earlier it was working fine"* So what in your environment has changed? Although really this sounds like a question you should be addressing to your sys admin or network team.

Comment: Is name-resolution properly working on your server?(Both IP-to-name and name-to-IP should work.)